# Importing of ES6 module in web-browser not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to export a class from filename **module_class.js** and then import the same class in another file called **dummyClass.js**. 
         In my dummyClass.js i am creating a new object and then calling a method which prints the value of a property on the console. In my **dummyClass.html** i have the tag **type="module"**, inspite of this, I dont see the output getting displayed. Following is the code. I am not sure What I am missing here?

```
> aryan@SuperMaN$ cd modules_in_js
> aryan@SuperMaN$ ls 
 dummyClass.html dummyClass.js  module_in_class.js  
 modules 
> aryan@SuperMaN$ cd modules/
> aryan@SuperMaN$ ls module_class.js
```

module_class.js

```
 export class Circle {
    constructor (radius) {
        this._radius=radius;

    }

    draw() {
        console.log(`THE RADIUS :- ${this._radius}`);
    }
}
```

dummyClass.js

```
import { Circle } from './modules/module_class.js';

const c=new Circle(10);
c.draw();
```

dummyClass.html

```
<body>
    <p id='demo'> SEE THE CONSOLE.LOG TO UNDERSTAND THE JAVASCRIPT CODE </p>
    <p id='demo1'> </p>


    <script  type="module" src="dummyClass.js"> </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code is working, it successfully prints `THE RADIUS :- 10` to the console. Are you using a modern browser which supports the ES6 syntax and also has support for ES6 modules?

Comment: It does support ES6 Syntax but i am not sure about ES6 modules. I am running chrome browser with version "Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)". How will i find out the same?

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) your version of Chrome (70.0.3538.77) does support ES6 modules. Also, how are you loading _dummyClass.html_, are you opening it via your local file system or via _localhost_? It should be via _localhost_, (or actual server), and the `.js` file/modules(s) must be served with the the JavaScript MIME type [text/javascript](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages:javascript-mime-type).